# How Do REPL Interpreters For Compiled Languages Work?

Tags: c#

I cant even begin to understand how they work, its a very broad question i guess. How is it possible that one could take a language such as C# which is compiled to IL for the CLR, then further JIT compiled into machine code at run time, and write an Interpreter or REPL for it as implemented in the [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) project. How did they get that right?

Comment: The mono source code should be available. Why not take a look?

Comment: While I don't think this anyone actually created a pure C# interpreter, your language indicates fundamental confusion which I'd like to address. A language is neither compiled not interpreted, it just is. Language *implementations* are compilers or interpreters, and both apply to any language (in fact, they can be readily converted into one another, although the result will be inefficient).

Comment: This is easy if you language has an incremental compiler, such as IronScheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the issue? Machine code is just some data (laying in virtual memory pages which are executable). You can produce that data, then, since it is also code, run it.

You can produce machine code in memory in various ways. For example, you could use [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or [libjit](http://freecode.com/projects/libjit) or many other libraries (or even make your own).

Some implementations of some langauges (I was thinking of the [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) implementation of Common Lisp) are even able to translate to machine code every line you are interactively typing. And this is not new, some 1957 computers did it (e.g. the French [CAB500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAB500) for PAF).

You can even generate some source code (e.g. in C), fork a compilation process, then dynamically load that code, e.g. with [dlopen(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Current compilers and processors are fast enough to make that compatible with delays for user-friendly interaction. My [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) domain specific language (to extend GCC) does that successfully.

AS commented by millimoose, [Mono](http://mono-project.com/) is free software, so you can study its code.

The **equivalence of code and data is a fundamental property of computers**. Likewise the equivalence of numbers and demonstrations in a fundamental insight of [Gödel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del) and [Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing) (and when you hear your favorite MP3 music, you use that too).